# listView inside of a linear layout with something else

Tags: android, android-layout

i was just wondering if it was possible to have in one layout xml file, maybe a vertical linear layout at the top have a horizontal linearLayout and then below that (inside of the vertical layout) have a list view that takes up the rest of the screen?

I couldnt find any information specifically on this, and i'd like to know if its possible before i attempt it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the ListView `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`. It will take up the remaining space not used buy the sibling LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width:match_parent
    android:layout_height:match_parent
    android:orientation:vertical >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width:match_parent
        android:layout_height:wrap_content
        android:orientation:norizontal >

    <!-- other views --->

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width:match_parent
        android:layout_height:0dp
        android:layout_weight:1 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, i figured it would be like this but wasnt sure. appreciate it